# How to display hindi / marathi texts using php and mysql on webpage

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I am developing website using php and mysql and i have stored Marathi data in database and displays on web page but its shows like ????????.
To solve this i have used utf8 Unicode i have set database and table to utf8 also added below code in connection file after the connection 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); function

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mysql_query("SET names=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mysql_query("SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci");
```

also set the `$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` before data fetch query the question mark problem solve now but the data displays "**0au120bhu908hgsbdch761**" like that.

Comment: With `php` you can use `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`. More about : http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: You need to read 'UTF-8 All the way through' - https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/80836

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> in your head. and stop using mysql api. It is removed since php 7.0

Comment: I tried everything but still getting output u092cu0947u0938u093fu0915 u0915u0949u092eu094du092au0941u091fu0930 for the word बेसिक कॉम्पुटर in database table, any one can tell me step by step process to solve issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Do *not* use PHP's `mysql_*` interface.  Switch to either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
2. See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)
3. `SELECT HEX(...) FROM ...` ("Test the data", at the link) to see what got stored.  For most Indian character sets, I would expect 3-byte does: `E0 Ax yy` or `E0 Bx yy`.
4. See "Best Practice' (at the link); it may help you home in on what else needs fixing.  Searching for `question marks` may help now.